# Azure Function couldn't load 'System.UriTemplate'

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-standard

I'm using .Net Standart for Azure Function which is working with Service Bus handling messages. Once my function get run i experienced the following exception:

> Microsoft.ServiceBus: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Constants' threw an exception. Microsoft.ServiceBus: Could not load type 'System.UriTemplate' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

I have installed following packages:
1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs
2.Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus
3.System.ServiceModel.Primitives

Any ideas why it can happen?

Comment: Could you offer details like your function code and project info from file `functionappname.csproj`?

Comment: It is possible that this is an issue with version inconsistency across your nuget packages or the lack of the appropriate nuget for System.ServiceModel. Unfortunately, there is no way of assembly redirects in Functions, so just try to match the packages and versions.

Answer (score -1):

Please try workaround mentioned in issue https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2824